# Calling next() twice in Iterator throws a NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, android, iterator

I'm retrieving several values from a sequence, but need to do so twice for a separate set of values coming from the same sequence. If I call one or the other, everything comes back to me correctly, but calling `next()` twice results in a `NoSuchElementException`. After reading about this online, I've gathered that after calling `next()` once, any other time after that calling it again will basically return the iterator false. How do you get two separate sets of data from the same `Collection`?

```
while (ai.hasNext()) {
   String ao = ai.next().getImageURL(ImageSize.MEGA);
   String an= ai.next().getName();
}
```

Comment: create two separate iterators over the same data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can store next() as a temporary variable. Replace Object in the following code with the datatype you are iterating through.

```
while(ai.hasNext()){
    Object temp = ai.next();
    String ao = temp.getImageUrl(ImageSize.MEGA);
    String an = temp.getName();
```

}

Answer (score 2):

If you are not sure your list has an even number of elements, you just need to add `if (ai.hasNext())` before your 2nd call to `next()`.

```
while (ai.hasNext()) {
   String ao = ai.next().getImageURL(ImageSize.MEGA);
   if (ai.hasNext())) {
      String an= ai.next().getName();
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: If you are *not* sure your list has an even number of elements, you need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You will run into this error when your collection has an uneven number of elements, you shouldn't call `next()` twice without checking there is something there; you're essentially breaking the point of the `while loop` by doing that.

`next()` will work as long as there's something in the collection to get. This is a code example that works perfectly fine on JDK1.6.0_23

```
    Collection<String> aCollection = new ArrayList<String>();

    aCollection.add("1");
    aCollection.add("2");

    Iterator<String> i = aCollection.iterator();

    String firstString = null;
    String secondString = null;

    while (i.hasNext()) {
        firstString = (String) i.next();
        secondString = (String) i.next();
    }

    System.out.println(firstString);
    System.out.println(secondString);
```

If you add another `String` into the `Collection` you will end up with a `NoSuchElementException` as you have described. You either need to have two seperate iterators over the same data, or you need to put another check within your `while` loop to check that there's still something left in the collection before trying to get it out.